# Obter valor retornado em uma URL com JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Preciso criar um script bem simples que faça um pequeno cálculo.

Tenho uma URL que retorna um valor no seguinte formato: 10,00, algo assim:

**https://dominio/api/produtos.php?pid=10&get=price&billingcycle=monthly**

Eu preciso criar uma função que pegue o valor retornado dessa URL e realize uma subtração desse valor (-5.00), em seguida imprima o resultado em um `<span>` que tem uma ID específica.

```
<span id="result"></span>
```

Como posso criar uma função desse tipo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer uma requisição à API e calcular sobre o resultado seria algo assim:

```
function makeRequest() {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            calcPreco(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "PONHA_SUA_URL_AQUI", true); // true para asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function calcPreco(preco) {
    preco = preco.replace(",", ".");
    preco -= 5;
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = preco;
}
```

---

Para recuperar o preço que esteja num parâmetro da url seria algo assim:

```
function calcPreco(){
   let preco = new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("get");
   preco -= 5;
   document.getElementById("result").textContent=preco;
}
```

Caso você receba um número com `,` no parâmetro (algo como `10,50`) faça:

```
function calcPreco(){
   let preco = new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("get");
   preco = preco.replace(",", ".");
   preco -= 5;
   document.getElementById("result").textContent=preco;
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou aqui, será que é por que ele retorna o valor com vírgula na URL?

Comment: números flutuantes em JS são com `.` ao invés de `,`... Seria, por exemplo, `10.50` ao invés de `10,50`

Comment: E tem como converter isso na função? Pois não posso alterar na API.

Comment: sim, basta fazer um replace do valor... algo como `preco.replace(",", ".");`... O código da resposta foi corrigido para adicionar esse useCase.

Comment: Estranho, não ta imprimindo o resultado no span..

Comment: Uma dúvida, o que seria o searchParams.get?

Comment: creio ter entendido errado teu problema, essa solução pega o valor passado pela url... o que você quer na verdade é fazer uma requisição pra esta url e calcular o preço sobre a resposta certo?

Comment: Isso, exatamente...

Comment: verifica se a nova resposta te ajuda

Comment: Tem algum modo específico para chamar essa função? Testei aqui e ainda não consegui fazer imprimir o resultado.

Comment: depende da lógica do teu código, poderia ser por exemplo: `<body onload="makeRequest()">`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82199/discussion-between-wendler-and-lucas-duete).